# Hibernate with MySQL : Auto-Generate Id : Equivalent of Sequence (Oracle) in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

As far as i Understand, when 'Native' class is used for auto id generation in Oracle, a single hibernate sequence is created, from where all the IDs are supplied to whichever table needed.

But i dont see this happen with MySQL. Instead, id's for each table start with 1.

Please correct me if am wrong.

Also, if i want the same tu happen on MySQL, what should be done.

Thanks All.

Raj.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> As far as I Understand, when 'Native' class is used for auto id generation in Oracle, a single hibernate sequence is created, from where all the IDs are supplied to whichever table needed.

This occurs if you don't specify any sequence name, unlike this:

```
<generator class="sequence">
  <param name="sequence">employer_id_seq</param>
</generator>
```

And actually most of time, people do NOT want a unique sequence, they prefer one sequence per table.

> But I don't see this happen with MySQL. Instead, id's for each table start with 1.

With MySQL, the `native` generator will default to an `identity` strategy i.e. will use identity columns, which are per table.

> Also, if I want the same to happen on MySQL, what should be done.

By same, I guess you mean using sequential IDs for all your entities. Give the [`table`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id-enhanced) generator a try :

```
<generator class="table">
</generator>
```

But this won't perform as well as sequence or identity columns. Also, people usually tend to prefer not sharing IDs between entities as I already wrote. I would think about this again.